# My virtualbox fstab will not auto-mount on reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, mount, fstab

I am able to mount my drive manually like this (ubuntu):

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf C_DRIVE /mnt/saga_c
```

But when I try and add it to my fstab it does not mount when I restart the machine. Is there something wrong with my /etc/fstab line:

```
C_DRIVE         /mnt/saga_c     vboxsf   defaults         0   0
```

Do I need something in addition to the vboxsf? Or is there something else I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: I'd try adding an explicit `auto` to the mount options. It can't hurt and quoth mount(8): "Some of these options could be enabled or disabled by default in the system  kernel."

Comment: If you've got a **systemd** based system try looking at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1097468/233795

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try removing the "defaults 0 0" part. Just a hunch.

Found this (put this instead of the `defaults`):
`rw,uid=1000,gid=1000`

Report back. :)

Comment: Have to leave right now but I will try it tonight and get back. Thanks!

Comment: This is how my fstab looks now and it seems to be working. Thanks!

C_DRIVE         /mnt/saga_c     vboxsf   auto,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000   0   0

Comment: After a night of frustration, here I am with a satisfied smile on my face. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Running debian jessie as host, i used the option `comment=systemd.automount` in my `/etc/fstab` to get it working (in addition to the suggestion of Azizur):

```
Share /var/sfshare vboxsf auto,rw,uid=33,gid=33,umask=0007,comment=systemd.automount 0 0
```

`uid`, `gid` and `umask` were set for compatibility with owncloud (v7.0.4) to use the mount point as data folder.

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/48578/fstab-mount-with-virtualbox-shared-folders/

Comment: I tried different solutions pointed out on superuser/stackoverflow/interwebs - but the important option is the `comment=systemd.automount` - with all other it would fail at my systemstart.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me on Ubuntu 11.10 Server:

/etc/fstab line:

```
sites   /home/rob/sites vboxsf  auto,rw,uid=1000,gid=33 0 0
```

`uid 1000 = my user, gid=33 www-data` (apache group on ubuntu..)

```
/etc/rc.local

mount /home/rob/sites
```

Answer (score 1):

After quite a bit of searching I found this [VirtualBox/SharedFolders Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders#The_name_was_not_valid).

try:

> sudo chmod 777 /mnt/saga_c

This worked for me.

Comment: `chmod 777`: nonononono! Never ever run `chmod 777`. It is practically never required! Not even for "testing purposes". If the file is readable, then it's readable. If it's writable by the `user` or `group` that need to write to it, then it's writable. There is absolutely zero need to give everyone write permissions, and forgetting to `chmod` it back to something sane is exactly how multinationals get hacked. Just don't do it. Ever. I wrote [an introduction of Unix permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35895436/660921). Please read it!