# How to add a command in /etc/rc.local file?

Tags: linux, mount, file-sharing

I installed Fedora in Virtual Box with host windows xp.
I want to share file between host and guest. Someone suggest me to run the command in fedora

```
#sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 F_DRIVE /home/menjar/Desktop/xp
```

where F_DRIVE is the F drive in xp I am sharing and 'xp' is the folder in fedora where I want to mount.
Now It works but when I reboot, I can't see the contents of xp folder anymore.
After goggling I find a suggestion that say to add the command in `/etc/rc.local` file. I am very new in linux so I want to know how do I do this.
I have tried to do this by using vi editor by running `#vi /etc/rc.local` and I add the line

```
 sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 F_DRIVE /home/menjar/Desktop/xp
```

and save by pressing `Esc` and then `:wq` but after doing I couldn't see any result. It still doesn't work.

So please explain how do I do this step by step (I am very new and don't know anything about Linux)? Am I doing something wrong with the command? should I have to place a '#" in front of the command while placing the line in /etc/rc.local? Please explain how do I solve it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding the line to the /etc/fstab file, so the volume can be mounted at boot time.

A guide is here:

http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html

You must be root to edit the file, so you will start with:

```
sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

Your line will look like this:

```
F_DRIVE    /home/menjar/Desktop/xp    vboxsf    uid=1000,gid=1000    0 0
```

You maybe want to add rw to the mount options.

For troubleshooting also look at: [My virtualbox fstab will not auto-mount on reboot?](https://superuser.com/questions/146763/my-virtualbox-fstab-will-not-auto-mount-on-reboot)

Comment: True of course. I was trying to get the question answered rather than providing a solution to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

The file belongs to `root` (the administrator account) so you won't be able to write to it as a normal user.

The solution is to run `vi` as root with the sudo command. `sudo vi ...`

Comment: Actually, running `sudoedit` is preferred: 1) which editor is used is decided by VISUAL / EDITOR; 2) the editor itself runs without superuser priviledges. Actually, allowing a user to `sudo vi` is a grave mistake by the admin, unless you *want* the user to have full root access to the system.

Comment: Thanks, never knew about sudoedit, that's a handy command, and definitely safer.