# Automounting a virtualBox partition on RHEL - EmergencyMode at Boot

Tags: linux, virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux, fstab, automount

Question referenced:

[My virtualbox fstab will not auto-mount on reboot?](https://superuser.com/questions/146763/my-virtualbox-fstab-will-not-auto-mount-on-reboot)

I am trying to mount a vboxsf partition on RHEL7 at startup.

```
mount -t vboxsf share /home/user/Windows
```

works fine after i login.But to automate it I modified the **/etc/fstab** file with the following line.

```
share /home/user/Windows    vboxsf defaults 0 0
```

or

```
share /home/user/Windows    vboxsf rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

Implementing both puts the RHEL in emergency mode at bootup, where if i comment out these lines from the fstab file the boot process proceeds as usual.

I tired adding "vboxsf" to the list of modules in the **/etc/modprobe.d/modules.conf** file

But if the stated line is present in the **/etc/fstab** file, I end up in emergency mode at bootup.

RHEL Linux Server 7.3

**uname -a :** Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 19 11:24:13 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

I believe your fstab syntax is wrong, you need to specify the full path for the first field. Try to use something like /path/to/share. As per man (5) fstab:

> For  ordinary  mounts  it will hold (a link to) a block special device
>   node (as created by mknod(8)) for the device to be mounted, like
>   `/dev/cdrom' or`/dev/sdb7'.  For NFS mounts one  will  have 
>   :,  e.g.,  `knuth.aeb.nl:/'.

Comment: Tried it.. results in the same Emergency Boot..